# How to apply Singleton Attribute for NonTriggered method in Azure Webjobs

Tags: azure-webjobs

If I apply [Singleton] and [NoAutomaticTrigger] attributes and publish the webjob, it goes to pending restart state.

We want to solve multiple instance issue which is occurring in a method.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> it goes to pending restart state.

In your case, you need to check the reason why webjob goes to pending restart state.

There are lots of reasons that goes to pending restart state. maybe due to an issues or webjob thread is finished needs to restart. We could check it with Webjob log.

Before publish it to azure, we make sure that it works correctly locally and  add the appsetting **AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage** with storage connection string then we could get the webjob log from webjob dashboard.

If you publish it as continuous type webjob, and method is executed completely. And the status will become to pending restart. It is a **normal behavior**.

**[Singleton] and [NoAutomaticTrigger]** attributes could work correctly, please refer to the following demo code.

```
 static void Main()
 {
    JobHost host = new JobHost();

    host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("CreateQueueMessage"), new { value = "Hello world!" + Guid.NewGuid() }); 

  }

[Singleton]
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public static void CreateQueueMessage(TextWriter logger,string value,[Queue("outputqueue")] out string message)
{
    message = value;
    logger.WriteLine("Creating queue message: ", message);
    Console.WriteLine(message);

 }
```

[image]